# Same route return different view according to user role laravel 9

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a column on my user table called role, and it can have 2 different values, "employer" and "employee".

What I want to achieve is, on /dashboard url;

if not logged in : return welcome view

if logged in as employer : return employer.dashboard view

if logged in as employee : return employee.dashboard view

Problem with this code is, I'm logging in with my employer user, and when I go to /dashboard, it sends me welcome view even though I'm logged in. It works fine with employee user. However when I switch places of two routes, Employer page works but Employee breaks. ( redirects to / ) It always uses last declared route instead of following the middleware.

My routing:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('role:employer')->group(function() {
    Route::view('/dashboard', 'employer.dashboard')->name("dashboard");
});

Route::prefix('store')->middleware('role:employee')->group(function() {
    Route::view('/dashboard', 'employee.dashboard')->name("dashboard");
});
```

Role middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HasRole
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string $role)
    {
        if (Auth::user()?->role != $role) {
            return redirect()->route('welcome');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Routes are reviewed in a top down manner, meaning the first route that is matched is executed. You'll want to move `employer` and `empolyee` routes above the `welcome` route so that they are reviewed first. Assuming you're not authenticated and neither `role` is matched, the non `employer/emplyee` `welcome` route will be processed.

Comment: Well yes, that first line was a mistake, I deleted it now, since I have that as fallback on my middleware. But my problem still continues. When I log in as employee, I get the employee dashboard just fine. But when I log in as employer, dashboard route redirects me to "/" as if I'm not logged in at all. But if I move employer route to be the last one in routes list, it works fine but employee route breaks ( redirects to / ) So no matter what I do, it tries to redirect me to last declared route instead of following the middleware. It's been 3 days, I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest moving the routing logic to a closure or controller, which would be much easier.

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    if (auth()->user()->role === 'employer') {
        return view('employer.dashboard');
    } else {
        return view('employee.dashboard');
    }
})->name('dashboard');
```

And then for the middleware, you can just update the already available middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated` to route the user to the home page if not logged in. Or just update `RouteServiceProvider::HOME`.